# Matching polynomial is real rooted

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $ G=(V,E) $ be a graph. A set $ F \subset E $ is called a matching if no two edges in $ F $ share a vertex. Define the matching polynomial of $ G $, $ M_{G} $ as: $$ M_{G}(x)=\sum_{F \text{  matching }} x^{|F|} $$ Show that $ M_{G} $ is real rooted.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Start by showing that for a tree $T$ then $x^{|T|}M_T(-1/x^2)=\det(Ix-A_T)$ where $A_T$ is the adjacency matrix of $T$. Since $A_T$ is symmetric it follows that the polynomial $\det(Ix-A_T)$ is real rooted.

A useful reference can be found  [HERE](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/lect25-15.pdf) (although the definition of matching polynomial is a bit different).

Comment: As a point of interest, $M_G(x)$ will always have $x=-1$ as a root.

Comment: @quasi Really? Take $G$ a star graph with $n>1$ vertices. Then $M_G(x)=1+(n-1)x$, which has only one root: $x=-1/(n-1)$.

Comment: @quasi From the definition it follows that $M_G$ is a polynomial whose degree is less or equal the cardinality of $E$. Now, for the star graph with $n$ vertices, $|E|=n-1$.

Comment: Got it. I misread the definitions. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for straightening me out on this.